# Two Safari's at once?

Tags: macos, safari

The goal is to have two (or more) versions of Safari accessible on my mac at the same time. I know this is possible because I have done it with iMovie 9. I now can run iMovie 9 and the latest version of iMovie at the same time. I need the older version of Safari for web development.

I think the only way for me to do this is to copy it from another older mac or find it online. To have an older version or newer version of an app, just select the app and do command-c and to paste it do command-v. To prevent your copy from being updated, copy it to an external drive.

If someone is still running a version of OS X between 10.7 and 10.10, you should have the versions of Safari I'm looking for. We can collaborate and do something on Google Drive to move the app across to my mac.

Strange question but I think that this question could benefit a lot of people especially those who do web development such as myself.

I currently have the latest version of Safari (9.0.1) on OS X El Capitan.

Since Apple only offers the latest version of Safari to download, the only way to get an old version to a 'new' computer is to copy it over.

Comment: You could use VMs with different versions of Safari and OS X and you will need to run a Safari from 10.7 on 10.11

Comment: @mark I have already looked at creating a VM in virtual box but the process is long and complicated and I would like all my apps to run natively if possible.

Comment: I suspect you need to as Safari in old running (if at all) on a newer OS might well not behave the same as on the version of OS it ran on. For testing you use the same OS and app versions as your users use

Comment: True, I'll give it a try (although I would prefer a native solution). Which VM application do you suggest?

Comment: Just to be clear, you specifically want different versions of Safari... not just multiple instances of the same version. Is this right? If so, not sure if there's a solution. If not, have you tried Fluid (http://fluidapp.com). It builds site specific browsers which are basically stand alone Safaris.

Comment: I'm just looking to have a copy of an older version of Safari. I only need someone who has OS version between lion and yosemite who would be willing to copy their Safari app and send it to me. That's it, simple. My second choice will be the VM although I would rather not since that means sacrificing performance of the computer and having to manage windows and resources for multiple operating systems. My memory usage is usually high anyway even though I have 16gbs because of the background programs I usually have running. Your suggestions are good but I like my original solution best.

Comment: I know someone who has a macbook pro which isn't being used who might let me barrow it long enough to "upgrade" from snow leopard through yosemite so that I could grab the various safari versions.

Answer (score 3):

You can run a semi-autonomous second instance by downloading and installing the webkit nightly build. You could run an older build if you're not keen to experience the bleeding edge bugs that sometimes creep into the builds.

- http://nightly.webkit.org

It's not truly a second safari, but you don't get your hands dirty worrying about two instances of the app trying to read / write to the same files for history, bookmarks, etc...

Comment: I tried it repeatedly with several versions of the webkit build and I get this error message `Nightly build of WebKit are not supported on OS X 10.11 at this time`.

Comment: @www139 Hmm - I'm running Version 9.0.2 (11601.3.9, r192684) of WebKit on 10.11 now but I'm prerelease OS X 15C47a / 10.11.2 so maybe that's the key?

Comment: [WebKit r192179](http://builds.nightly.webkit.org/files/trunk/mac/WebKit-SVN-r192179.dmg) was [built on 10 November 2015](http://web.archive.org/web/20151110033948/http://nightly.webkit.org/) and *is* compatible with OS X 10.9.5. Cross reference [Latest version of Webkit Nightly that supports Mac OS 10.9.5? | MacRumors Forums](http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/latest-version-of-webkit-nightly-that-supports-mac-os-10-9-5.1960856/)